# Can i make a batch file that makes my bot send some random msg to MSTeams?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

Im trying to make my bot be able to send msg to msteams without being on msteams with batch file. But i just cannot find a way to get past this error.

ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - no security token sent.

So if anybody has any idea if making a batch file like this is possible please help me.

Im sending @BOT 1234 as mention to /api/messages since the bot sends data if hes mentioned but if theres a another way please tell me.

My code in BATCH FILE:

curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"text\": \"@BOT 1234\"}" https://myaddress.ngrok.io/api/messages

Comment: The error message states "no security token sent"... Your bot will have to obtain a security token that it can include in the request

Comment: @phuzi Thats pretty much what im asking how to get the security code included in batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on your comment saying you're getting a "no security token sent" message, I would suggest you to check the microsoft docs for authenticating a bot service request [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)

Basically you need a **Bearer access token** than you add to each request in the **Authorization header**

To request an access token follow the steps below:

## Step 1

#### Request an access token from the MSA/AAD v2 login service

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MICROSOFT-APP-ID&client_secret=MICROSOFT-APP- 
PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default
```

## Step 2

Add the access token from the response to your bot service call

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at 
[proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive)

Then call a custom webmethod https://myaddress.ngrok.io/api/batch in your batch